# Программа работает с багом

Tags: kotlin

У меня есть такой класс `MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
    private val categoriesArray = ArrayList<TextModel>()
    private var number: Int = 0
    private var adapter = Adapter()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding?.root)
        val array = arrayListOf("if", "else", "{", "}", "()", "{", "}")
        binding?.apply {
            rcView.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL)
            rcView.adapter = adapter
            array.forEach {
                number++
                categoriesArray.add(TextModel(it,number))
            }
            adapter.updateAdapter(categoriesArray)
        }
    }
}
class Adapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ThemeHolder>() {
private val courseArray = ArrayList<TextModel>()
var isNewLine=false

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ThemeHolder {
    val viewBinding =
        TextItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    return ThemeHolder(viewBinding,isNewLine)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ThemeHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.setData(courseArray[position])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return courseArray.size
}

class ThemeHolder(private val binding: TextItemBinding,private var isNewLine:Boolean) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun setData(text: TextModel) {
        binding.apply {
            binding.textView.text = text.text
            card.setOnClickListener {
                if(text.text == "{"){
                   isNewLine=true
                }
                whatNumber(text,isNewLine)


            }
        }
    }

    private fun isSelectedCheck(text: TextModel, top: Float) {
        if (text.isSelected) {
            animateViewToOriginalPosition(top)
        } else {
            animateViewToUp(top)
        }
        text.isSelected = !text.isSelected
    }

    private fun whatNumber(text: TextModel,isNewLine:Boolean) = with(binding) {
        if(isNewLine) {
            card.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
            isSelectedCheck(text, 400f)
        }else {
            card.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
            isSelectedCheck(text, 500f)
        }
    }

    private fun animateViewToUp(top: Float) = with(binding) {
        val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
            card,
            "translationY",
            0f,
            -top
        )
        animator.duration = 1000
        animator.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
        animator.start()
    }

    private fun animateViewToOriginalPosition(top: Float) = with(binding) {
        val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
            card,
            "translationY",
            -top,
            0f
        )
        animator.duration = 1000
        animator.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
        animator.start()
    }
}


fun updateAdapter(newList: List<TextModel>) {
    courseArray.clear()
    courseArray.addAll(newList)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

И я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на элемент, который имеет текст равный фигурной скобке, все последующие элементы располагались ниже на 100 пикселей, но программа работает вот так:
[image: Результат работы программы]

Как можно изменить код, чтобы программа работала по моей задумке?

Comment: Для начала хотя бы попытайтесь перебрать "все последующие элементы" и расположить их "ниже на 100 пикселей". Код за вас писать некому.